# python merge unsorted lists

Tags: python, list, merge

How can I merge 2 arbitrary unsorted lists `a` and `b` while preserving
the order from both lists? I do not want to discard duplicates or sort.
Formatting of whitespace is just to allow visualization for human readers:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'X',       'Y',      '127'      ]
b = ['a', 'b',      'X', '44', 'Y', 'w', '127', 'X' ]
```

Desired output `m`:

```
m = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'X', '44', 'Y', 'w', '127', 'X' ]
```

I should specify the merge order more concisely.
    Matching priority goes to list `a`:
    Attempt to match every item in list `a` to an item in `b`

```
So if  a = ['b',      'a', 'r', 'n']
and    b = ['b', 'r', 'a',      'n'],
merged m = ['b', 'r', 'a', 'r', 'n']
```

A dictionary solution deletes duplicates (`b[2]` and `b[7]` both are `'X'`).

This needs to be programmatic; I'm looking at millions of lines of data. `difflib` is interesting, possibly for another problem, but I don't think it helps with this one.

I am using Python 2.7.12 on Windows-7

The code below solves this problem, but it is not as clean and simple as I would like.

```
def merge_lists(a, b):
    """ Merge 2 arbitrary unsorted lists a and b while preserving
    the order from both lists. Do not discard duplicates or sort."""

    ia = ib = 0
    m = []    
    if len(a) == 0:
        m = b
    elif len(b) == 0:
        m = a

    while ia < len(a) and ib < len(b):
        if a[ia] == b[ib]:
            m.append(a[ia])
            ia += 1
            ib += 1
        else:
            count = b[ib:].count(a[ia])
            if count == 0:
                m.append(a[ia])
                ia += 1
            else:
                k = b[ib:].index(a[ia])
                for i in range(ib, k+ib):
                    m.append(b[i])
                ib += k

        if ia >= len(a):
            for i in range(ib, len(b)):
                m.append(b[i])
        if ib >= len(b):
            for i in range(ia, len(a)):
                m.append(a[i])

    return m #--- END --- merge_lists()
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! As you may be aware, SO is a question-and-answer site. Readers, such as yourself, ask questions and other readers attempt to answer them. Your post is missing the essential element of an SO post -- the question! What, precisely, is your question?

Comment: The way that you inserted spaces in your literals for `a` and `b` seems to be under-specified. Please explain the logic (which is a good first step for writing the code.

Comment: You didn't define the *order* of the new list well enough: for example, say `a=[1]` and `b=[2]` what should be the result ? `[1,2]` or `[2,1]` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: What output do you expect when your two lists are `['b', 'a', 'r', 'n']` and `['b', 'r', 'a', 'n']`?

Comment: @Olian04: Heck no. This has pretty much nothing to do with that question.

Comment: If you can combine those lists into one (a+b or b+a isn't exactly working for me with your expected order, or I would have posted this as an answer); you can then use this answer to remove dupes without losing the order: http://stackoverflow.com/a/480227/2302482

Answer (score 3):

You can probably use `difflib`, but you'll have to do the merging yourself.  This can be tricky -- And isn't always easy to do with a computer (consider when you have to manually merge conflicts in your Version Control System).  However, a lot of cases *can* be handled automatically.

Here's some code to help get you started -- I don't guarantee it works in all cases, so if you find inprovements, please feel free to let me know and I'll try to edit them in:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'X',       'Y',      '127'      ]
b = ['a', 'b',      'X', '44', 'Y', 'w', '127', 'X' ]
import difflib
matches = difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=a, b=b).get_matching_blocks()

# Pointers to locations in the `a` and `b` lists to keep track of our progress.
ix_a = 0
ix_b = 0
c = []
for match in matches:
    # Add in missing elements from `a` -- Assume `a` comes first?
    if match.a > ix_a:
        c.extend(a[ix_a: match.a])
    # add in missing elements from `b`
    if match.b > ix_b:
        c.extend(b[ix_b: match.b])
    # add in common elements.
    part = a[match.a:match.a + match.size]
    c.extend(part)

    # update our pointers into the original sequences.
    ix_a = match.a + match.size
    ix_b = match.b + match.size

print(c)
```

Obviously you're a little bit at the mercy of exactly how `difflib` chooses to match runs in the data as well.  e.g. the example that was pointed out by @ZeroPiraeus: (`'barn'` and `'bran'`)<sup>1</sup> results in `'brarn'`, but if you reverse the order of the inputs you get `'baran'`.

The surprising thing here isn't that the two results are different -- Indeed, it's somewhat natural to expect them to have different orderings if you change the order of the inputs.  However, It probably *is surprising* that they have completely different values (one has two `'r'` and the other has two `'a'`).

<sup><sup>1</sup>I'm formatting these lists as strings for the sake of brevity.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

There is no single correct result, as the problem is specified. For example:

```
a = ['b',      'r', 'a', 'n']
b = ['b', 'a', 'r',      'n']
m = ['b', 'a', 'r', 'a', 'n']
```

```
a = ['b', 'r', 'a',      'n']
b = ['b',      'a', 'r', 'n']
m = ['b', 'r', 'a', 'r', 'n']
```

Comment: A bit confused as to whether I should up-vote this answer

Comment: @smac89 Oh, you definitely should ;-)

Comment: @smac89 less flippantly, [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer) may be relevant to your quandary.

Comment: I agree with that meta-post.  However, I don't necessarily agree that it justifies this answer :-).  Saying "This is not possible" is very different than saying "This is under-specified".  The meta-post seems to talk about the former whereas this answer is trying to say the latter.  It may well be that _either_ of the merges would be acceptable in this case.  Personally, I feel like this would be better as a comment for OP demonstrating the need for further clarification.

Comment: @mgilson it's borderline, I'll grant that. What pushed me into answering (rather than expanding on the comment I'd already made) was that formatting, including whitespace, clarifies the issue significantly. I would certainly nudge OP toward accepting your answer over mine, (and have only failed to upvote yours because I've also failed to read it properly), but I still think mine is more illuminating than a comment could be. I won't be particularly upset if you feel it deserves a downvote, though.